# Which type should be used to save data?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have a 3D array. The range of the array is from -100.0 to 2048.0 and they are float numbers. I want to decide which type of data should be used float/float16/float32...in PYTHON, such as its size small as much as possible. Currently, I am using float32 to save the arrays (1000 3D-array), results in 2GB. Can I reduce its size by using another type such as float/float16?

Comment: It depends on how much precision you want.

Comment: How are you saving the arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some info about float types can be found using numpy's `finfo` function. As seen below the the maximum value for a `float16` is 65504.0 so the value range (-100.0 to 2048.0) will fit. The problem might be that the epsilon (`eps` and `epsneg` below) is too large so that two distinct values will be treated as the same. With a `float32` the epsilon values are much smaller and as such you can represent values with a higher precision.

```
> import numpy as np
> print(np.finfo(np.float16))
Machine parameters for float16
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =   3   resolution = 1.00040e-03
machep =    -10   eps =        9.76562e-04
negep =     -11   epsneg =     4.88281e-04
minexp =    -14   tiny =       6.10352e-05
maxexp =     16   max =        6.55040e+04
nexp =        5   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------

> print(np.finfo(np.float32))
Machine parameters for float32
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =   6   resolution = 1.0000000e-06
machep =    -23   eps =        1.1920929e-07
negep =     -24   epsneg =     5.9604645e-08
minexp =   -126   tiny =       1.1754944e-38
maxexp =    128   max =        3.4028235e+38
nexp =        8   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------
```